# Support Map fragment inside list item adapter returning null second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, null, adapter, supportmapfragment

I am Completely using fragments in my app.First one activity is loaded and then fragments come over this activity and then destroy.My Problem here is i am trying to load support mapfragment inside listview adapter when clicked on a button inside list item,it works fine for first time but second time

```
        gmap = ((SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

this line is returning null inside my adapter.what should i do to rectify this problem here.
I am calling map fragment inside adapter like this in oncreateviewholder method of my adapter.

public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Activity context;
List<ListDetails> products;
SharedPreference sharedPreference;
public static com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader imageLoader;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ViewHolder holder;
protected String Day = "";
public static View alertLayout;
private static GMapV2Direction gmapdirection;
 public static  GoogleMap gmap;
 protected Document doc;

 public ProductListAdapter(Context context, List<ListDetails> products) {

        this.context = (Activity)context;
        this.products = products;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader(); 

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView productNameTxt;
    TextView Ratingsno;
    TextView productPriceTxt; 
    TextView timedist;
    TableLayout distancesection;
    TextView categoryname;
    ImageView favoriteImg;
    RatingBar rb;

    ImageView OfferImage;
    ImageView MapImage;

    NetworkImageView listimage;
    public TextView distance;
    public ImageView indicator;
    TextView timer;
    TextView Postedon;




      public ContactViewHolder(View v) {

      super(v);

      productNameTxt = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.name); 
        productPriceTxt = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_description);
        distance = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.listview_distane);
        timedist = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.timedist);
        Ratingsno = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.Ratingsno);  
        Postedon = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.Postedon);
        favoriteImg = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.fav_checkbox);

        rb = (RatingBar) v
                .findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
        timer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        categoryname = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.Categoryname);
        listimage = (NetworkImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        distancesection = (TableLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.distancesection);


        MapImage = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.imgmap);

      }
  }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, final int position) {

    try {


        String text = "<font color=#222222>"+products.get(position).getShopName()+"</font>"+"<small><font color=#0091EA> ( </font></small>"+" <small><font color=#0091EA>"+products.get(position).getAreaName()+"</font></small>"+"<small><font color=#0091EA> ) </font></small>";
        contactViewHolder.productNameTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

        //holder.productNameTxt.setText(product.getShopName() + "  " + "( " + Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0091EA'>" + product.getAreaName() + "</font>") + " )");
        contactViewHolder.productPriceTxt.setText(products.get(position).getDeal() + "");
        contactViewHolder.rb.setRating(Float.valueOf(products.get(position).getRatingAvg()));
        contactViewHolder.Ratingsno.setText(products.get(position).getTotalRatings() + " Ratings"); 
        contactViewHolder.timedist.setText(products.get(position).getTime());
        contactViewHolder.distance.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getDistance())+ " Km");
        contactViewHolder.categoryname.setText(products.get(position).getCategoryName());
        contactViewHolder.listimage.setImageUrl(products.get(position).getListImage(), imageLoader); 


        contactViewHolder.MapImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

                     if (alertLayout != null) {
                         ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) alertLayout
                                 .getParent();
                         if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                             parentViewGroup.removeView(alertLayout);
                         }
                     }

                        //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_map_dialog);

                     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                     dialog.setContentView(alertLayout);

                       // dialog.setTitle("Map Directions");




                        ImageView cancel = (ImageView) dialog
                                .findViewById(R.id.cancel);


                        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                        });

                        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

                        dialog.show();

                         LoadPlaceDetails(products.get(position).getLat(),products.get(position).getLng(),products.get(position).getAreaName(),products.get(position).getCategoryName());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();            
                        PostLogcatErrors ple = new PostLogcatErrors();
                    ple.PostLogcatErorrs(e);
                }
            }
        });

        if (checkFavoriteItem(products.get(position))) {
            contactViewHolder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
            contactViewHolder.favoriteImg.setTag(context.getString(R.string.red_favcolor));
        } else {
            contactViewHolder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.unchecked);
            contactViewHolder.favoriteImg.setTag(context.getString(R.string.grey_favcolor));
        }
        contactViewHolder.Postedon.setText("Posted On" + "  " + products.get(position).getPostedDate());

        contactViewHolder.timer.setText(products.get(position).getOfferEndTime()); 



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1) {
     View itemView = LayoutInflater.
             from(arg0.getContext()).
             inflate(R.layout.list_item4, arg0, false);

     LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



     //Here i am adding Map layout


     if (alertLayout == null)
            alertLayout = li.inflate(R.layout.list_map_dialog, null);





 return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}

public boolean checkFavoriteItem(ListDetails checkProduct) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<ListDetails> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (ListDetails product : favorites) {
            if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}

private void LoadPlaceDetails(double destlat, double destlng, String areaname,String Category) {
    try {
        LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(SplashScreen.nwLocation.getLatitude(), SplashScreen.nwLocation.getLongitude());

        LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(destlat, destlng);

        gmapdirection = new GMapV2Direction();

        FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) context)
                .getSupportFragmentManager();



      //Here i am loading map after click on Map button


        gmap = ((SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();




        gmap.clear();
        gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(fromPosition,13));

        gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(fromPosition)
                .title("Current Location")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))).showInfoWindow();;

                        switch (Category) {
                        case "book_store":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition)
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_book, ""))));
                            break;
                        case "beauty_salon":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition)
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fashion, "")))); 
                            break;
                        case "electronics_store":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition) 
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_electronic, ""))));
                            break;
                        case "food":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition)
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_food, ""))));
                            break;
                        case "home_goods_store":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition)
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home, ""))));
                            break;
                        case "restaurant":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition)
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_job, ""))));
                            break;
                        case "real_estate_agency":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition)
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_realestate, ""))));
                            break;
                        case "travel_agency":
                             gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(toPosition)
                                .title(areaname)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.ic_vehicle, ""))));
                            break;
                    }



        Document doc = gplaces.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition,
                GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING,gmapdirection,gmap, context);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
        PostLogcatErrors ple = new PostLogcatErrors();
        ple.PostLogcatErorrs(e);
    }

}
```

}

am i doing anything wrong here? suggest me on this..thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are deleting SupportMapFragment inside R.id.map. But you show us too little code to know what is wrong.

Comment: By now I can only sugest
changing 

((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();

to 

((FragmentActivity) context).getChildFragmentManager();